# RNN vs ResNet for multivariate time series prediction

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, gru

All others being equal, would a ResNet-based or RNN-based neural network (with/without an attention mechanism) perform better for forecasting a multivariate time series?

### Related:

- [Deep learning for time series classification: a review](http://Deep%20learning%20for%20time%20series%20classification:%20a%20review) explains that a ResNet performs rather well on multivariate timeseries classification (and I assume thus also on forcasting). Yet a comparrison with a RNN based network is missing.
- [Forecasting Multivariate Time Series
  Data Using Neural Networks](https://ntnuopen.ntnu.no/ntnu-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/2559922/18579_FULLTEXT.pdf?sequence=1) (link downloads a .pdf) seems to conclude that a Convolutional Neural Network outperforms a LSTM-based network for time series forecasting.
- [CNN vs RNN for time series classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297970/cnn-vs-rnn-for-time-series-classification) asks the same question about RNN vs CNN (altough for classification, not for forecasting), yet no conclusive answer is given.
- [Data Preprocessing and Augmentation for Multiple Short Time Series Forecasting with Recurrent Neural Networks](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309385800_Data_Preprocessing_and_Augmentation_for_Multiple_Short_Time_Series_Forecasting_with_Recurrent_Neural_Networks) describes a LSTM with skip connections (so basically a RNN/ResNet hybrid) which also seems to perform well.